# unable to add .net core 2.2 to visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0, .net-core-2.2

I'm creating a Winforms (.Net Core) application in Visual Studio 2019, the project is created with .Net Core 3.0 which has no designer. I have downloaded and installed .Net Core 2.2 and .Net Core 2.1 SDKs but they are not being added to Visual Studio and still the only available option is .Net Core 3.0

Am I missing something?

Comment: WinForms support was added in core 3.0, so I wouldn't expect earlier SDKs to support it.

Comment: Oh Really, previously I have used only .net framework for winforms and .net core for web, I didn't know .net core did not support winforms. Thanks, then I go with .Net Framework

Comment: You may want to look at [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/winforms) on porting WinForms to core, as it looks like it has a work around for the designer issue in the form of multiple projects. Probably not ideal, but may work for your purposes until a designer is supported.

Comment: I prefer to go with .Net Framework it is a small project for myself, I'm gonna go the easy way. Thanks a lot. You saved me lots of time

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/  <-- the WinForms designer is available as an extension because it's still in preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't able to use .net core versions previous to 3.0 due to the fact that [Windows Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#windows-desktop) support is, in fact, a new feature to core 3.0.

@madreflection has pointed out in comments that there is a [designer for WinForms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/) that will work in core 3.0, but it is currently in preview. This may prove sufficient for your purposes in the interim, but you may be looking at sticking with Framework until the designer is out of preview.